# Is there a function $f$ so that $f(x-\exp(y))$ is linear in $y$

Tags: functions, transformation

I wonder if there is any continuous function $f$ so that $f(x-\exp(y))$ is linear in $y$. I exclude cases where $f$ is a constant or depends on $x$ or $y$. For instance, I do not allow $f(c)=\ln(x-c)$.

Comment: Does linear in $y$ mean $f(x-\exp(\lambda y+k))=\lambda f(x-\exp(y))+f(x-\exp(k))$?

Comment: @FShrike, I would interpret $f(x-e^y) = \alpha(x) + \beta(x) y$.

Comment: That's *linear* vs *affine* (often called linear, especially in undergrad math).

Comment: Should it be linear/affine for every value of $x$ or just for a fixed value of $x$?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I have to agree with the preceding commenters, in that I have no idea what is being asked.

Comment: @PierreCarre interpreted correctly. And I assume the function is linear/affine in $y$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such $f$. Indeed, fix $x$ and suppose $f(x - \exp(y)) = a(x) + b(x) y$ for all $y$. Then $f(w) = a(x) + b(x) \log (x - w)$ for all $w < x$. If this also holds for $x'$ then $f(w) = a(x') + b(x') \log(x' - w)$ for all $w < x'$. It follows that $(x - w)/(x' - w)$ is a constant for all $w < \min(x, x')$, which is nonsense.

Comment: This function $f$ depends on $x$. It looks like there is no transformation that makes $x-\exp(y)$ is affine in $y$...

Comment: Indeed that's what's shown here.